# Django servers not starting after installing live server

Tags: python, django

reloading the site every time was very frustrating to me so i thought to look for a live server for djanglo

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 11, in main
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
  File "C:\Users\piyush\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 
52
    except ImportError,e:
                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

and this is the error popping now when i used python manage.py runserver command
https://pypi.org/project/django-liveserver/

the server i installed

Comment: It's hard for me to understand what you are trying to do. Explaining the syntax will not help in this case I think. Can you describe more about what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The highlighted syntax is valid for Python 2 only.
The package you've installed is not compatible with Python 3.

Beside that, it's not what you want anyway if you want live reload:

> A backport of the Django 1.4 LiveServerTestCase for 1.3

Instead consider something like http://livereload.com/ ...

Comment: How should i fix it is there any wat to get live server with my configurations

Comment: Fix it by uninstalling the package and removing it from your configuration. As I linked, you might want to look into e.g. Livereload or similar packages.